# How to fix this error "Cannot enable the location service. Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing android and ios applications using native script-angular. I am using the native script-geolocation plugin to access the current location. I am also using native script-plugin, firebase plugin in my app. I can't enable the location in android using native script-geolocation in my app. How to fix the issue?

Iam using the plugin versions:
nativescript-firebase = 7.3.0
geo-location = 5.1.0

This issue only occurs on the android platform, in ios, it was worked. I also set the app.gradle properties like

```
android {  
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "id"  
    multiDexEnabled true
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  project.ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
    }

  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }

}
```

Iam getting the following error:

```
Cannot enable the location service. Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbck;
```

Comment: Sorry could you please elaborate, do you get runtime exception when you call location services? Firebase plugin v7.3.0 is pretty old, which version of tns runtime you are using?

Comment: Yes iam getting run time exception while enabling location services

Comment: tns runtime means what android run time?

Comment: Yes, that's what I had asked.

Comment: iam using 5.3.1

Comment: Can you post complete error log, which class is actually throwing exception.

Comment: Please see above i have posted the complete error

Comment: Did you try `googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.+"`?

Comment: where to put this googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.+"?. i tried with inside of AppResources/Android/app.gradle

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: Yes correct. Did you try a clean build after updating that.

Comment: yes, i was tried cleaning the build..but it was not working.

Comment: Try `15.0.1` in app.gradle if still issue persists try it on `before-plugins.gradle` as discussed in the related [Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/issues/172#issuecomment-442413281).

Comment: ok thank you manoj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you manoj for suggesting this link  [Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/issues/172#issuecomment-442413281). I have fixed the issue by updating google play services in android sdk and also i was creadted the before-plugins.gradle file and added the google play services configuration like below

```
android {  
  project.ext {
      googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add location version () dependency in the gradle. It will solve your problem

```
dependencies {
 // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.+'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:x:y:z' //where x.y.z is a version. for eg. use 21.0.0 for latest stable.
//  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```